# In Teradata SQL how to get random number between a pair, coming from field/column?

Tags: teradata, random

I am recently got stuck upon a simple problem in Teradata: how to get random number between a pair of number coming from field/column?

The function RANDOM( lower_bound , upper_bound ) apparently is restricted to only accept fix number rather than field / column name.

```
--THIS ONE FAILS:
WITH TRIAL(CATEGORY, VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX) AS (
SELECT 'A', 0, 3 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 9 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2, 5 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 1, 12 FROM CTE
), CTE(DUMMY) AS (SELECT 'X')
SELECT T.*,
RANDOM(T.VAL_MIN, T.VAL_MIN) --HERE'S THE PROBLEM
FROM TRIAL T;

--THIS ONE WORKS:
WITH TRIAL(CATEGORY, VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX) AS (
SELECT 'A', 0, 3 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 9 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2, 5 FROM CTE UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 1, 12 FROM CTE
), CTE(DUMMY) AS (SELECT 'X')
SELECT T.*,
RANDOM(1, 7) --HERE'S THE PROBLEM
FROM TRIAL T;
```

I'm pretty sure there's simple solution for this. Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a number within the requested range:

```
RANDOM(0, 2147483647) mod (T.VAL_MAX - T.VAL_MIN +1 ) + T.VAL_MIN
```

But there might be a minimal bias towards the lower numbers due to MOD, e.g. for 1-3 you get following probablities:

```
1,2 = 715,827,883 / 2,147,483,648 
  3 = 715,827,882 / 2,147,483,648
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lower numbers 1-3" that leads to the bias? Does it mean narrower range? Heaps of thanks :)

Comment: Check the calculation, for 1 & 2 there's 715,827,88**3** vs 715,827,88**2** for 3 :-)